# Counting error in background job

Tags: parse-platform

I'm having trouble implementing a simple (or so I thought) counting Background Job on parse cloud:

I have:

- a Country class which has about 200 countries.
- a Channel class which currently has only 1 object (for testing).

Basically the idea is that for each country, there can be several channels. **Using Parse Relation to link the two classes seemed kind of an overkill, so I simply put a String field called "country" in the Channel class and a String field called "name" in the Country class.**

What I'm trying to do now is counting the channels linked to each country, using a background job. Ever country has a field called "nbrChannels" which is supposed to be equal to the number of channels with the corresponding "country" field. But I'm getting some weird results:

The code I thought would finally work (after many different tries):

```
Parse.Cloud.job("channelsPerCountry", function(request, status) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var countryQuery = new Parse.Query("Country");
countryQuery.each(function(country) {
    var countryName = country.get("name");
    var n = -1;

    var channel = Parse.Object.extend("Channel");
    var channelQuery = new Parse.Query(channel);
    channelQuery.equalTo("country", countryName);
    channelQuery.count({
        success: function(number){
        n = number;
        country.set("nbrChannels",n);
        return country.save();
        },
        error: function(error){     
        }
    });

    }).then(function() {
    status.success("Channels per country successfully counted.");
    }, function(error) {
    status.error("Oops, something went wrong!");
    });
});
```

When I run this job on Parse.com, the job status is "successful" and the log shows nothing special.

**But in the Data Browser not all countries are updated:**

**For most of them, nbrChannels = 0 but for about 30 of them, which seem completely random, nbrChannels = -1** (meaning the counting, or the country.save() didn't succeed) and **their "updatedAt" field shows that they haven't been updated at all.**

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I really don't understand how that is possible...

When I searched for answers I came accross another way of implementing a query.count in a job, so I tried this:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("channelsPerCountry2", function(request, status) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var countryQuery = new Parse.Query("Country");
countryQuery.each(function(country) {
    var countryName = country.get("name");

    //var channelQuery = new Parse.Query("Channel");
    var channel = Parse.Object.extend("Channel");
    var channelQuery = new Parse.Query(channel);
    channelQuery.equalTo("country", countryName);
    return channelQuery.count().then(function(number){
        country.set("nbrChannels",number);
        country.save();
        }, function(error){
        console.error("error counting:" + error);
    });

    }).then(function() {
    status.success("Channels per country successfully counted.");
    }, function(error) {
    status.error("Oops, something went wrong!");
    });
});
```

This gives worse results: the log shows:

```
Failed with: Oops, something went wrong!
I2014-07-26T18:19:36.606Z] error counting:[object Object]
```

Does anyone know what this error means and why it fails?

Thank you for all the advice and answers you might give me! I've really been having trouble with this one for days!